# Error response from daemon: {"message":"page not found"}

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running `docker-compose up -d` command and getting the following error message.

```
Error response from daemon: {"message":"page not found"}
```

I am new to the Docker and not sure what's causing this issue. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

I have reinstalled Docker but still it did not work.

Comment: Can you add your docker-compose.yml? The error message is caused by an invalid Docker API usage caused by docker compose.

Comment: I am unable to edit this question. can you answer any possible solution?

Comment: You can't edit your own question? 
Unfortunately I cannot help you with any further possible solutions. Your question misses relevant information such as your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Ok, this question has now a duplicate located at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77977025/error-error-response-from-daemon-messagepage-not-found