# ERROR: Error response from daemon: {"message":"page not found"}

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting this `Error response from daemon: {"message":"page not found"}: driver not connecting` error in docker.

[image: default builder]

[image: Available Builder]

I reinstall docker still i am getting this error. As i am new to the docker check not able to solve the above error.

Comment: Try to completely uninstall Docker from Windows using this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167323/12818462

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error response from daemon: {"message":"page not found"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975901/error-response-from-daemon-messagepage-not-found)

Comment: No still i am getting that error